# php compare operator doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, mysql

i have a really strange problem. My Code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT emailIsConfirmed FROM userdatabase.user where username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string( $db, $username ) ."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0]);
    var_dump("1");
    if((mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0]) == "1")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

doesn't work. Even when the output looks like this:

```
string(1) "1" 
string(1) "1"
```

the result is false... Why?

I guess it is a really silly mistake.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Calling a function twice is not necessarily the same as calling it once and using the return value twice. Very basic mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array` called the second time tries to fetch the second row of the results.
Comment your `var_dump`s and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The result comes from these:

```
var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0]);
var_dump("1");
```

Which means that `if((mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0]) == "1")` is true.

Remove `var_dump()` calls unless you want to debug the database result

Comment: sehr cool danke es geht alles wieder :D